# Make Git SSH deal with advanced login

Tags: git, ssh

I would like to sync my local repository with a clone on a compute server to which I have ssh access. I could not set up a working remote (from the local repository's perspective), however, and I assume this is because the server prompts for which compute node I would like to use when opening a new ssh connection. Is there a way I can inform git about this step, i.e. to configure git such that when the ssh connection is established, it first sends a compute node ID before going on to other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

If you can establish connection with plain SSH you can use connection sharing and use that established connection with git.

You need first configure your SSH by adding these lines in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
```

Next create directory for connection objects `mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets`

Then you have to make plain SSH-connection to your server: `ssh server.com` or `ssh -fN server.com` and git will use the already established connection and you don't have to login or do anything else interactive.

---

References

http://frankenbyte.tumblr.com/post/33747851865/faster-github-using-ssh-multiplexing
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, for I think your approach could have worked. Unfortunately it doesn't, however. It is true that I don't have to provide my password the second time, but the server still asks which compute node I would like to use.